# A categorial PCF theory?

Tags: set-theory, topos-theory, infinity-categories, infinity-topos-theory, pcf-theory

I'm not an expert in PCF theory, so please forgive me if this question makes no sense.

I'm looking for a categorial version of PCF theory.

Specifically, if we replace $Set$ with another category, what properties must it have for the famous $$pp(\aleph_{\omega})< \aleph_{\omega_4}$$ to hold in some generalized way?

Also, what happens if we change the geometric realization from simplicial to globular (or some other $\infty$-category)?

Comment: I don't understand the last sentence. What does geometric realization have to do with anything? Are you asking for an $\infty$-categorical PCF theory?

Comment: @TimCampion Yes, if we replace $Set$ then when we talk about cardinalities, it is natural to fix a realization of an $\infty$-category to mean our "cardinality" functor. This is the only sane formulation I could think of for an "abstract PCF theory"

Comment: I think I'm starting to see what you mean. You're using the term "geometric realization" (which normally means [something different](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/geometric+realization)) to mean that you have an abstract $\infty$-category, and you're choosing to represent it in some particular model of $\infty$-categories (such as quasicategories or Batainin globular $\infty$-categories). I would pump the brakes on such considerations -- first of all, one should figure out what's going on for ordinary categories before worrying about $\infty$-categories.

Comment: When you say "cardinality functor" I also don't know what you mean. For example, the function from $Set$ to the partial order $Ord$ which takes cardinalities is not functorial (although it is functorial in injective maps).

Comment: Indeed, the morphisms in $Set$ and $Ord$ are "not suited for the job". We could instead use the set of injective maps on one side and ordinal interval object on the other side (which makes sense for PCF) - which makes this a functor of closed categories.

Comment: I think I see the natural [left-closed structure](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/closed+category#basic_definition) on $Set^{inj}$  that you're talking about, where $[X,Y]$ is the set of injective maps from $X$ to $Y$. But I'm not clear on how ordinal interval maps are to make $Ord$ into a closed category -- is the underlying category still a poset? What are the composition maps $L^X_{Y,Z} :[ Y,Z] \to [[X,Y],[X,Z]]$? And surely wouldn't it be more natural to work with $Card$ rather than $Ord$? Moreover, I don't see how to define a closed functor between these categories.

Comment: You're right on both points. Taking injective maps only is too coarse for defining composition. But instead if we look at $Set^{inj}$ as an $\infty$-category (with the natural Cisinski model structure?), it may be 
more interesting (where we do have composition defined up to finite homotopy).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97983/discussion-between-omer-rosler-and-tim-campion).